# How to list all free dynos in my heroku account?

Tags: heroku, heroku-cli

I have an account in heroku. In that account, there are lots of Apps, each app had different kinds of dyno's.

I got a mail saying my free dyno is getting used up and I have to upgrade.

To find out which app has the free dyno is so tedious.

Since I have to fetch the list of dynos for every app using the command `heroku ps -a appName`.
Is there any command to list all free dynos in my Heroku account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While logged in visit this link: https://dashboard.heroku.com/account/billing

[image]